# Is it possible to change SSL cetrt file paths in Apache according to domain?

Tags: php, apache, ssl

We're using Ubuntu + Apache2.4.
PHP app works with dynamic number of domains (stored in db).
I'm looking the way to add LE certs to domains. So the question is how to change SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile for apache according to domain?

Comment: Create a new apache configuration for each domain, and place the SSL cert info in each configuration.

Comment: @aynber, I don't know on the start which domains will be used by app. Those are users domains, so they can register and add new domain to app.